# How to link html pages beforehand uploading process

Tags: html, cpanel, href

I am a novice front-end developer trying to build a website using HTML, CSS, and bootstrap. I would like to ask you a couple of questions regarding the uploading process. I am about the purchase a domain for the website I have been building so far. However, I have encountered some problems. Currently, I can link my HTML files to provide the transition between different pages within the website(As my code shown below). My question is, how can I set the correct directory to provide the transition between the HTML pages. As far as I know, after the uploading process to Cpanel, href directory has to be modified. How can I provide the right href directory to carry out transitions within the website before uploading my website to public_html? Thank you in advance.

```
<li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\enver\Desktop\practice\index.html">Mainpage<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\enver\Desktop\practice\aboutme.html">About me<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\enver\Desktop\practice\services.html">Our Services<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\enver\Desktop\practice\contact.html">Contact<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\enver\Desktop\practice\blog.html">Blog<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to link like

```
href="C:\Users\enver\Desktop\practice\contact.html"
```

use

```
href="contact.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this you create a website folder at the desktop, in this folder add a pages folder where you will put your other service pages and others. You keep the index file.html at the root.

Mainpage(current)
    
    
      About me(current)
    
        
    Our Services(current)
    
        
    Contact(current)
    
        
     Blog(current)
    
when you're going to send herberger just the pages and index folder.html your css and don't forget to reach your css again in the pages services and other href=".. /css/.."

Comment: Thanks for the help and what do you mean by saying keep the index.html at the root. I didn't understand that part